# Can we enable mysql binary logging for a specific table

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I want to write a listener which detects the DML changes on a table and perform some actions. This listener cannot be embedded in the application and it runs separately.

I thought let the application write to blackhole table and I will detect the changes from the binary log file.

But in the docs I found that enabling binary logging slows down the mysql performance slightly. Thats why i was wondering is there a way i can make the mysql master to log the changes related to a specific table.

Thanks!

Comment: " detects the DML changes on a table and perform some actions " Have you tried TRIGGERS ?

Comment: the actions include calling a java method it is outside mysql so triggers wouldnt help

Comment: What is the issue here ? Aren't you able to **track the DML change** OR you are able to track DML but not able to **write the listener** ? It will be a bad coding practice to call any function code outside database using trigger/stored procedure.

Comment: whenever the application writes to a table. my listener should do some processing on that record and relay to an api. i first thought the listener could search for pending records every 5 seconds but i am exploring for other ways to do it. I need to know the best way to track a DML change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is the best way to track DML change and call function based on that. But, as you want to explore other options you may try

1. writing a cronjob with [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) which includes SELECT / SHOW statements as well which you don't need
2. `mysqlbinlog` : It slows down performance just a little, but it is necessary for point in time data recovery and replication.

**Suggestions:**

- On a prod environment, MySQL binary log must be enabled. and general
  query log must be disabled as general query logs almost everything
  and gets filled very quickly and might run out of disk space if not
  rotated properly.
- On a dev/qa environment, general query log can be enabled with proper
  rotation policy.